# Running total of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `SQL` snippet which gives me an output similar to below, except the `RUNNING_TOTAL` column. I'd like to add the `RUNNING_TOTAL` column where the the numbers adding up from the last record upwards as per the example below.

| ROW NUMBER | CHANGE | INVENTORY_COUNT | RUNNING_TOTAL | DATE | USER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Some reason 1 | 31 | 30 | Date 1 | John |
| 2 | Some reason 2 | -1 | -1 | Date 2 | Kate |
| 3 | Some reason 3 | 1 | 0 | Date 2 | Peter |
| 4 | Some reason 4 | -1 | -1 | Date 3 | Parker |

Can this be achieved in SQL? I have tried to wrap the current query with `SELECT *, SUM(INVENTORY_COUNT) AS 'RUNNING_TOTAL')` and had no luck.

**Current SQL query:**

```
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date) ROW_NUM, 
 A.Change as 'CHANGE', 
 A.InventoryCount AS 'INVENTORY_COUNT', 
 A.Date AS 'DATE', 
 A.Users AS 'USER' 
FROM(
    SELECT 
    'Stocktake' as 'Change',
    STK.stock_count as 'InventoryCount',
    stk.time_stamp as 'Date',
    STK.count_user as 'Users'
    from IWS_STOCK_TAKE STK WHERE product_code='F100020D'

    UNION
    SELECT
    'Stock pick' as 'Change',
    -1 * abs(picks.PickedQty) as 'InventoryCount',
    picks.picked_time as 'Date',
    picks.PickedBy as 'Users'
    FROM IWS_ORDER_PICKS picks WHERE ProdCode='F100020D'

    UNION
    SELECT
    'Purchase receipt' as 'Change',
    rcv.RECEIVED_QTY as 'InventoryCount',
    rcv.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP as 'Date',
    rcv.RECEIVER as 'Users'
    FROM IWS_PURCHASE_RECEIVED rcv where PRODUCT_CODE='F100020D'

    UNION
    SELECT
    'Stock Adjustment' as 'Change',
    ADJ.VAR 'InventoryCount',
    ADJ.PROCESSED_DATE as 'Date',
    ADJ.USER_ID as 'Users'
    FROM IWS_STOCK_TAKE_ADJUSTMENTS ADJ where PRODUCT_CODE='F100020D'

) A
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to be using `UNION` here; there's no way your different datasets could return rows with the same value, as you define different *literal* values for the columns aliased as `Change`. Use `UNION ALL`. Also, don't use literal strings for aliases; it's the only place it works, it's confusing (for new and old hands) and some methods for literal string aliasing is deprecated. Use the T-SQL delimit identifier, Brackets (`[]`), or the ANSI SQL delimit identifier, double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the running total using a window function.  Based on the table you provided in your question:

```
select t.*,
       sum(total) over (order by date desc) as running_total
from t;
```

I'm not sure if you want to use `date` or `row_number` to define the last row.  Whichever goes in the `order by`.

If your table is generated by a complicated query, you can use a CTE and then run this on the CTE.